# Search 2 columns and return all matches in a transposed row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to take this `QUERY`:

```excel
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Items!$A$2:$D,"SELECT D WHERE A = '"&A2&"' and B = '"&B2&"' and C = '"&C2&"' and C is not NULL and D is not NULL", 0)),)
```

And turn it into a formula that I can enter one time at the top of a sheet and have it apply to all cells in the column below.

I've tried manipulating various other formulas and answers I've found/received here on SO, but getting nothing but errors.

[My sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-FdpxsNcrqXXWroYzeAQZz5TuyEX6xKnTif0rrrJl60/edit#gid=1201210002&range=A2)

Comment: Is there a particular sheet name, or are we discussing this generally?

Comment: I will eventually apply to several sheets, but specifically, 'subItemDataValidations!D2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Estimate!A2:A&Estimate!B2:B, 
 TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 {INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(Items!A2:A&Items!B2:B))*(LEN(Items!C2:C)),
 Items!A2:A&Items!B2:B&"♦"&Items!C2:C, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),,1), IF(
 ISNUMBER(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(Items!A2:A&Items!B2:B))*(LEN(Items!C2:C)),
 Items!A2:A&Items!B2:B&"♦"&Items!C2:C, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0)),
 QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(Items!A2:A&Items!B2:B))*(LEN(Items!C2:C)), 
 Items!A2:A&Items!B2:B&"♦♥"&Items!C2:C, )), 1, 1), "♦")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 limit 0", 0), )})
 ,,999^99))), "♥"))), {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I've attempted to modify this formula to search based on multiple columns without luck.  Currently, it's only taking the value of the first match (based on a single column), but I'd like for it match based on three columns (Task Group, Task, Action).

Comment: I believe that would be beyond VLOOKUP limitation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that enormous formula!  And to think I was trying to accomplish this using a simple `FILTER`.  Would this be the appropriate modification to include another column (column C) in the search criteria?

```excel
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP('task-itemAssociationsDV'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociationsDV'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociationsDV'!C2:C, 
 TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 {INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(taskData!A2:A&taskData!B2:B&taskData!C2:C))*(LEN(taskData!D2:D)), 
 taskData!A2:A&taskData!B2:B&taskData!C2:C&"♦"&taskData!D2:D, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),,1), IF(
 ISNUMBER(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(taskData!A2:A&taskData!B2:B&taskData!C2:C))*(LEN(taskData!D2:D)), 
 taskData!A2:A&taskData!B2:B&taskData!C2:C&"♦"&taskData!D2:D, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0)),
 QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(taskData!A2:A&taskData!B2:B&taskData!C2:C))*(LEN(taskData!D2:D)), 
 taskData!A2:A&taskData!B2:B&taskData!C2:C&"♦♥"&taskData!D2:D, )), 1, 1), "♦")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 limit 0", 0), )})
 ,,999^99))), "♥"))), {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}, 0)))
```